# Wpf + access dynamically generated data from Api

Tags: c#, wpf

Im new to wpf and learning c#.
I created a grid with stackpanel. Im actually generating Labels and Radio buttons, for QuestionName and Answers respectively, so for every question, its 1 label and 4 radio buttons.

If i want to save the current questionnaire, along with QuestionName and Selected Answers(the database part is ok).

I want to save the selected answers (radio buttons) along with the QuestionName, anyway how to access this dynamically generated data?

Im using WPF and C#, thanks

`Label testLabel = (Label)grid.FindName("lblTimer");` (this one works)
    `Label gName = (Label)CustomList.FindName("QuestID[i]");`(this one dont)

since im using a list to populate my data, it returns null, and i know that im doing it wrong but for the one who works, its a label that isnt dynamically generated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code for more help.

Comment: You should invest some time into learning MVVM and ViewModel First.  All of your user controls would be bound to an underlying ViewModel, you would not need to know anything about the View or the user controls on the View.  You would interact with the data in the ViewModel only.

Comment: actually thats what im doing in parallel but i just wanted a way straightforward to do that since im a beginner in c# thanks

Comment: I cannot test anything but this looks weird: `.FindName("QuestID[i]")`. Have you tried `.FindName(QuestID[i])` instead?

Comment: `int tname = CustomList.Children.Count;`
           `for (int i = 1; i < tname; i+=7)`
            `{`
                `string sid = CustomList.Children[i].ToString();`

works but looks weird too